# how to block specific charter inputs in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have the below asp.net code to get user input then using the below javascript i have make sure that it is not kept empty by the user. now what i want do is to block user input on few characters such as (|,@,#,$) using the same javascript. any suggestion on how can i do this?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="input" Enabled="False" onblur="CheckTxtBox(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

`function CheckTxtBox(sender) {
          if (sender.value == "") {
              alert("Please enter Address 1");
              return false;
          }
      }`

Comment: use the keycode of these keys and prevent them from clicking ,means when these keys are pressed by user find it via its keycode and do some validations

Comment: You must mention what you have tried. And its good that you have mentioned. One more thing is that you should also describe what you have achieved. For example: is your alert `alert("Please enter Address 1");` working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it here is what i did. now this takes only uppercase charters from (A-Z) and numbers from (1-9). thank everyone for your help. its much appreciated.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" 
                                Width="100%" CssClass="input" Enabled="False"  onkeypress="return isNumber(event);"></asp:TextBox>

//  this JS validates and prevent inputting symbols 
  function isNumber(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways you can do this

```
1) In  "keypress" event.Check the user press a character like (|,@,#,$)then stop them right there

2)  "onblur" event: when the input element loses focus, validate its contents. If the value is invalid, display a message
```

**Note**

the second method is better because if user is copy pasting the content then the first method will not catch them

**First method**

```
 function CheckTxtBox(e) {
        var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
        if (//charactercode of the keys as condition) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

**Second Method**

In your `onblur event` you can check your textbox value with a regular expression and validate it with regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckTxtBox(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

An your asp control :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="input" Enabled="False" onkeypress="return CheckTxtBox(event)""></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate keys/text entered in edit controls, Regular Expressions are recommended. Have a look at: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html for demos on few such validation examples.

But, it is not a good practice to stop the validation with the browser alone. Always do a validation at the server end. This is due to the fact that JavaScript can be disabled in browsers, which can allow non-validated data posts to the server.